# Нужен перевод для вкладки "Following" и "Bookmarks"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

Нужен перевод для вкладки "Following":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также для её содержимого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. На странице профиля также нет перевода (во вкладке "Активность"):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для закладок добавил:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14846.
2. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14847.
3. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14848.

Comment: Наверное уже _"статус-завершено"_

Comment: @EOF ага, спасибо)

Comment: @EOF я в таких случаях кидаю тревогу на вопросе с комментарием модератору. Всё равно это никто кроме ромбоносов выполнить не сможет. Но вообще, я немного удивился, когда "избранное" вдруг стало "закладками".

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ок. Буду знать

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Favourites поменяли на Bookmarks. Думаешь, нужно было оставить старое?

Comment: Я сначала думал, что просто перевод стал такой (Favorites - Закладки), вот это меня ужаснуло. Но когда там увидел Bookmarks, то понял, что это более существенные изменения. С другой стороны, люди к чему-то уже привыкли, и теперь терминология меняется. Скорее всего потом и звёздочку уберут из иконки закладки, т.к. сейчас это больше смахивает на потребность переходного периода.